# How to create object with type alias in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-alias

```
new BaseListState<BrandCriteria, Brand>()
```

This is working and I add

```
export type BrandListState = BaseListState<BrandCriteria, Brand>;
```

then

```
new BrandListState()
```

This is not allowed. Any way to fix this problem?

Comment: You've only declared a type. To `new` it, you need to have a constructor, too. Have a look at the error 'classes' in the RxJS codebase. They have both a type and a ctor: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/2365a54c391d9ef76ddc417f8f6dedb17cdb890e/src/internal/util/TimeoutError.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a Type Alias ([see doco here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#reusable-types-type-aliases)) which doesn't have constructor, so it can't be created with `new`. You need to create class for this

```
class BrandListState extends BaseListState<BrandCriteria, Brand> {}
```